# Pass vector of pointers by reference and replace a vector of void* pointers

Tags: c++

I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct{
int pktType;
void* sourcePeer;
void* destPeer;
void* aboutPeer;
int tree;
std::vector<int> cogSize; //LEAVE ?
std::vector<void*> newParents; //JOIN_REP
}packet;
```

In addition, I have a class named `base_peer` declared as follows:

```
class base_peer
{
    ...
public:
virtual void createMessage(int, base_peer*, base_peer*, base_peer*, int, std::vector<int>&, std::vector<base_peer*>&, packet*);
    ...
}
```

and the `createMessage()` function is defined as follows:

```
void base_peer::createMessage(int msgType, base_peer* msgSourcePeer, base_peer* msgDestPeer, base_peer* msgAboutPeer, int msgAboutTree, std::vector<int>& msgCogSize, std::vector<base_peer*>& newParents, packet* newPacket)
{
    newPacket->pktType = msgType;
    newPacket->sourcePeer = msgSourcePeer;
    newPacket->destPeer = msgDestPeer;
    newPacket->aboutPeer = msgAboutPeer;
    newPacket->tree = msgAboutTree;
    newPacket->cogSize = msgCogSize;
    newPacket->newParents = newParents;
}
```

I want `createMessage` to create a packet structure and assign values to its elements. More specifically, the errors happen when I try to assign to vector `std::vector<void*> newParents` a vector `std::vector<base_peer*>& newParents`.

I get the following errors from Eclipse:

> no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector' to
>   'const std::vector&'
>
> std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const
>   std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = void*; _Alloc =
>   std::allocator]
>
> no match for 'operator=' in 'newPacket->packet::newParents =
>   newParents' base_peer.cpp

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Why `void*` ? that's a code smell to me.

Comment: Actually I am using `void*` because I have a circular dependency issue: struct `packet` should be aware of `base_peer` class and reversely. I couldn't find a solution to this.

Comment: @user2397244: Try `vector<class base_peer*>` instead of `vector<void*>`

Comment: @user2397244: Perhaps you should have asked a question about that problem first.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley You are probably right: I thought void pointers would be a solution to the initial problem...

Comment: @user2397244 if you forward declare base_peer you should be able to use `base_peer*` instead of `void*` i.e. `class base_peer; type struct {...} packet;`

Comment: This isn't C code either, so drop the `typedef`, too. `struct packet {...};` works here.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to copy the elements over manually, or using iterators.  The simplest way is to use the `assign` member function of `std::vector`.

```
newPacket->newParents.assign(newParents.begin(), newParents.end());
```

This only works because any pointer is directly convertible to a void pointer.  If you were converting *from* void pointers, you would need to use a cast, which you could do with `std::transform`.

Answer (score 0):

After template instantiation, `vector<void*>` and `vector<base_peer*>` are totally different concrete classes with no inheritance relationship at all. Unless an assignment operator is defined it will not work.

You can do a `newPacket->newParents[index] = newParents[index];` as this will assign a pointer to a generic pointer.